# Getting more decimal positions as a result of division when using awk

Tags: awk

I have this problem,

```
awk 'BEGIN{ x = 0.703125; p = x/2; print p }' somefile
```

and the output is `0.351562.`  But a decimal number is missing. It should be `0.3515625` So is there a way to improve the division to get all decimals stored into a variable and not only printed? So that p really holds the value `0.3515625`

Comment: Fix your code to show `print p`

Comment: use `printf` instead of `print` like `awk 'BEGIN{ x = 0.703125; p = x/2; printf "%.10f\n", p }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the built-in value for `CONVFMT` (newer versions of `awk`) and `OFMT` is only 6 digit precision. You need to make it different by modifying that variable to use along with `print` or use `printf` with precision needed.

From [Awk Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html)

> `CONVFMT's` default value is `"%.6g"`, which creates a value with at most six significant digits. For some applications, you might want to change it to specify more precision. On most modern machines, 17 digits is usually enough to capture a floating-point number’s value exactly.
>
> Prior to the POSIX standard, `awk` used the value of `OFMT` for converting numbers to strings. `OFMT` specifies the output format to use when printing numbers with print. `CONVFMT` was introduced in order to separate the semantics of conversion from the semantics of printing. Both `CONVFMT` and `OFMT` have the same default value: `"%.6g"`. In the vast majority of cases, old `awk` programs do not change their behavior. However, these semantics for `OFMT` are something to keep in mind if you must port your new style program to older implementations of `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ x = 0.703125; p = x/2; printf "%.7f", p }'
```

In addition to that, OP want's this high-precision number in a variable for which `sprintf` should be used

```
awk 'BEGIN{ x = 0.703125; p = x/2; pcustom=sprintf("%.7f", p) }'
```

or by changing the `OFMT` variable on GNU Awk 4.1.4,

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFMT = "%0.7f"; x = 0.703125; p = x/2; print p; }'
```