# awk calculations giving rounded answers for larger numbers

Tags: awk

I have a Linux bash script which is calculating the total of some values in a file using awk. I am using this syntax to do the calculations:

```
$ awk "BEGIN { print $first_number + $second_number }"
```

For calculations where the answer is a number below 9999.99, it displays the answer correctly. Above that value, it rounds the answer to one decimal place, or no decimal places, etc. like this:

```
$ awk "BEGIN { print 89.54 + 6789.44 }"
6878.98

$ awk "BEGIN {print 1.66 + 68790.77 }"
68792.4

$ awk "BEGIN {print 1.66 + 687990.77}"
687992

$ awk "BEGIN {print 10100.66 + 6787990.77}"
6.79809e+06
```

I want the answer to show the decimals, and to 2 decimal places in all instances.

DO you know why it is doing the unexpected roundings?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on top of [James's useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59070460/5291015), there is a reason why you see that behavior. It is because the exact manner in which numbers are converted into strings is controlled by a predefined variable in `awk` called `OFMT` when using `print`

`OFMT's` default value is `"%.6g"`, which creates a value with at most six significant digits. If you want `print` to represent a more accurate representation, change it for e.g. to always represent 2 digits post the decimal point, something like `"%2.2f"`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%2.2f"; print 89.54 + 6789.44 }'
6878.98

$ awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%2.2f"; print 1.66 + 68790.77 }'
68792.4

$ awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%2.2f"; print 1.66 + 687990.77 }'
687992.43

$ awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%2.2f"; print 10100.66 + 6787990.77 }'
6798091.43
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889541/5291015) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50020201/5291015), which explains the behavior of these conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `print` is not the right tool to output decimals, use `printf` and appropriate modifiers:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", 10100.66 + 6787990.77}'
6798091.43
```

Also, use single quotes `'` around the awk program.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by others, the problem is with the number formatting: use `%.2f` with either `printf` or AWK's `OFMT` (that applies to `print`) to get two decimal places.

To pass your shell variables to awk, you can use the `-v` command-line option, e.g.,

```
$ awk -v a="$first_number" -v b="$second_number" 'BEGIN {
    printf "%.2f\n", a + b
}'
```

If you always have exactly two decimal places, you could also use integer arithmetic in bash without the decimal point, and only format the output:

```
$ printf "%.2f\n" $(( 1010066 + 678799077 ))e-2
```

(Of course this only works for arithmetic operations that maintain the number of decimals, e.g., addition and subtraction.)